# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'expoModule.Components.BlurView')

Tags: react-native, expo

I have build a app in react-native, expo
but I am facing some trouble with some error
[image : error when running on device or simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u41YG.png)
[This is my project issue link](https://github.com/venkatmanavarthi/dating-app/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you are importing `BlurView` properly.

`expo install expo-blur`

`import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur'`

If this isn't the issue can you show some code to get a better idea.